# Hibernate: jpamodelgen - Generate java instead of class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, metadata

I use hibernate-jpamodelgen for generate jpa metadata model.

I need to generate java file, into source directory, instead of class file in generate-sources directory.

It's possible?

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.5-jdk8</version>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase><!-- this is actually the default, could be omitted -->
                        <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                                <includes>
                                        <include>**/entity/*.java</include>
                                </includes>
                                <processors>
                                        <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                                </processors>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/entity/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
                </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Which IDE are you using? If you are using Eclipse/STS, then try setting the "Generated source directory" to "src/main/java/entity" by navigating to Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing. And check the "Enable annotation processing" and "Enable processing in editor" checkboxes as well.

Comment: ehm using intelli j community

Comment: Try setting the same things in IntelliJ at Preferences > Project Settings > Compiler > Annotation Processors

Comment: I found option but generated code is still .class files instead of .java

Comment: Ok , It was path problem. Now works fine. Please make comment as answer so I can vote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Which IDE are you using? If you are using Eclipse/STS, then try setting the "**Generated source directory**" to "**src/main/java/entity**" by navigating to **Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing**. And check the "**Enable annotation processing**" and "**Enable processing in editor**" checkboxes as well.

For IntelliJ, trying setting these properties at **Preferences > Project Settings > Compiler > Annotation Processors**